# How do you call the technique used in jazz where notes are repeated up and down

Tags: piano, jazz

I am looking for the technique in jazz appearing in the video at at 6:30 where a piano player plays something like an arpeggio. What is it called or is it just an arpeggio?

Comment: It's certainly not an arpeggio. it's just a riff that gets repeated *ad nauseum*. He liked the sound of it, so kept playing it.

Answer (score 1):

As Tim said in the comments, its not an arpeggio. I would call it an ostinato